# Shared locks taken under Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking, snapshot-isolation

I am seeing waits for shared locks (`LCK_M_S`) when using RCSI. My understanding is that this isn't supposed to happen since `SELECTs` do not require shared locks when using RCSI.

How can I be seeing shared locks? Is it because of foreign keys?

Answer (score 14):

> *How can I be seeing shared locks? Is it because of foreign keys?*

Yes. SQL Server reverts to the locking implementation of the read committed isolation level when accessing a table for the purpose of validating foreign key constraints. This is **required for correctness**, and cannot be disabled.

The behaviour applies only to data-modification statements. Shared locks are only taken when checking the foreign-key related data. Other data access in the same execution plan can continue to use row versioning.

If SQL Server did not do this, data-modification statements under `RCSI` could end up violating the foreign key constraint because the integrity check used out-of-date (versioned) data.

Unfortunately, there is currently no *supported* way to see this change in locking behaviour in an execution plan. It is possible to see the internal locking hints when trace flag 8607 is active.