# Read Committed Snapshot Isolation blocking during table modification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, blocking, snapshot-isolation

This is using SQL server 2014 SP2 (it was true in SP1 as well).

The database is configured to have Snapshot Isolation on and Is Read Committed Snapshot Isolation is set to true. The processes accessing the database do not set their isolation level, so they are defaulting to read committed.

I have a process that is modifying a specific table by deleting values (80,000 or so on average) from it and then inserting new ones, in a transaction.

I have an application that reads this same table, and only this table, in the database in Read Committed Snapshot Isolation.

The read is blocked with a LCK_M_IS. The Activity monitor shows that it is blocking on Object ID 1171535257 which is this table. The lock in the table is exclusive (Lock Mode X).

There is [no foreign key](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39628/shared-locks-taken-under-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-rcsi) on the table to explain the lock.

Can I prevent the Read process from issuing the LCK_M_IS or otherwise blocking, and have it read the committed data instead?

<sub>In a previous version of the question, an index was suspected as the culprit. Further testing has shown that even without any indexes this behavior is observed.</sub>

Comment: How many rows are getting deleted on average in the transaction?

Comment: @AntoineHernandez, around 80,000 or so, although the problem was observed at around 65,000

Comment: Does the process run more than once concurrently? Are you sure the table read is the head blocker and not the delete/insert process? It's possible SQL Server is doing lock escalation based on amount of rows getting deleted and that could still block a read. Read Committed Snapshot Isolation does not prevent blocking but can reduce it.

Comment: @AntoineHernandez, Either process could run more than once concurrently, although I don't think it was in this case. It is quite possible the delete/insert is the head blocker. What escalation level blocks a RCSI read?

Comment: Turns out there is a connection pooling problem where the isolation is not reset.

Comment: You have queries changing isolation mode? Any queries using nolock?

Comment: @AntoineHernandez, yes, others are, and then when the connection is pulled from the pool, it isn't actually using RCSI anymore, instead it is using Repeatable Read. The site won't let me delete the question, but it was based on false information. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing online rebuilds of this index at the same time as the transaction?
I have RCSI block if there is an index rebuild simultaneous with a large or long running transaction.
Paul Randal has a great explanation here: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-830-unicorns-rainbows-and-online-index-operations/

Comment: No, there is no online rebuild of the index.